# Java7 swing application framework support

Tags: java, swing, java-7

The future of the Swing application framework on the Java 7 platform is undefined.
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/archive/2009/08/19/saf-and-jdk7

Is it safely to use it now?

Answer (score 6):

Even though using SAF is fairly safe (cause it has nothing to do with JDK7), take a look at the [following](http://kenai.com/projects/guts/pages/Guts-gui) great alternative, created by developer, frustrated by slow progress of SAF

Comment: Thanks for the ad, eugener (I am the owner of Guts-GUI project). But beware that the project is on going development so unusable in a real application currently (hope I can offer a 1.0 version for Christmas;-)) Moreover, Guts-GUI depends on Guice (at list now, maybe next year I'll make it independent of the DI library).

Answer (score 4):

The [JDK 7 Features](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/) page says:

> **Dropped**
>
> **JSR 296: Swing application framework**
>
> An API to define the basic structure of a typical Swing application, thereby eliminating lots of boilerplate code and providing a much-improved initial developer experience

So, this looks like it is definitively dropped for JDK 7.

However, that does not mean that you cannot use it or that it is in any way "not safe" to use it (whatever you mean exactly with that), neither that the project is dead and will not be developed any further.